# How do you find the remainder when dividing polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

Suppose that $f=(x+1)^{100}+(x-3)^{100}$ and $g=x^2-2x-3$. What is the remainder of $\frac{f}{g}$? I know there must be something connected to the roots of $g$, but how I can use that? Also I know that the remainder's degree is less or equal to 1. I don't want the response, I want to find that by myself, hints are welcomed.

Comment: Reminder or remainder?  This post is now on Hot Network Questions and should probably be cleaned up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put $$f(x)=q(x)g(x)+r(x)$$ where $r(x)$ has degree $1$, and you are not interested at all in $q(x)$, what can you do to make life easier?

Comment: I can use the roots of $g$ to find $r(x)$. Oo, so easy!!

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

We have that $$f(x)=(x^2-2x-3)q(x)+ax+b.$$ Since $$x^2-2x-3=(x-3)(x+1)$$ we get

$$f(-1)=-a+b$$ and $$f(3)=3a+b.$$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that
$$\newcommand{\rem}{\operatorname{rem}}
\rem\!\big(p(x)s(x),q(x)s(x)\big)=s(x)\rem\!\big(p(x),q(x)\big)
$$
and that
$$
\rem\!\big(p(x),x-a\big)=p(a)
$$
Now, since $x^2-2x-3=(x-3)(x+1)$, what we are looking for is
$$
\begin{align}
&\rem\left((x+1)^{100},(x-3)(x+1)\right)+\rem\left((x-3)^{100},(x-3)(x+1)\right)\\
%&=(x+1)\rem\left((x+1)^{99},x-3\right)+(x-3)\rem\left((x-3)^{99},x+1\right)\\
%&=(x+1)(3+1)^{99}+(x-3)(-1-3)^{99}\\[3pt]
%&=4^{99}-3(-4)^{99}\\[3pt]
%&=4^{100}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Complicated solution with binomial theorem:

If you write $x-1=t$ then $q(x) = t^2-4$ and $$p(x) = 2\Big[{100\choose 0}t^{100}+...+ 
2^{96}{100\choose 96}t^4 +2^{98}{100\choose 98}t^2 + 2^{100}\Big]$$

Now let $s=t^2$ then $q(x) = s-4= q_1(s)$ and

$$p(x) = 2\Big[{100\choose 0}s^{50}+...+ 
2^{96}{100\choose 96}s^2 +2^{98}{100\choose 98}s + 2^{100}\Big]= p_1(s)$$

So the remanider when $p_1(s)$ is divided by $s-4$ is $$p_1(4)=2\Big[{100\choose 0}2^{100}+...+ 
2^{100}{100\choose 96} +2^{100}{100\choose 98} + 2^{100}\Big]$$
$$ = 2^{101}\Big[{100\choose 0}+...+ 
{100\choose 96} +{100\choose 98} + 1\Big] $$
$$ = 2^{100}\Big((1+1)^{100}+(1-1)^{100}\Big) =\boxed{2^{200}}$$

Comment: Please be nice???? It take 10 minutes of my life to write this down and then downvoted. Who is not nice? @robjohn